# In a large tab delimited file, get unique values of one field, sum their values in a second field

Tags: unique, csv

first post, I normally lurk, but I couldn't find anything that quite fit my situation.

So, I have a large tab-delimited file (~3 billion lines) with two fields on each line. One is a string of fixed length (10 characters, all alpha, all caps), the other is an integer of variable size. Some of the entries in the first field between lines are identical, like so

```
AAABBBCCCD    6
QQQQQQQQQQ    1
ZZZTOPZZZZ    299
AAABBBCCCD    14
JHFDSJKHFJ    2
ZZZTOPZZZZ    1
```

What I want to do is compare values in the first field, find the unique ones, and sum every second field value for those unique entries, resulting in an output like this,

```
AAABBBCCCD    20
QQQQQQQQQQ    1
ZZZTOPZZZZ    300
JHFDSJKHFJ    2
```

I don't necessarily care if they're sorted by integer value, but it would be cool if they were. Not really a priority.

I've already tried some things in perl that *work* on test files but perform much too slowly to be useful on the real thing. So, yeah, I'm open to any sort of solutions, but I'm particularly interested at this point if there is any cool/clever bash-fu that would do the job.

Comment: Just an idea, but have you tried doing the file in batches of, say, one million lines to partially coalesce the data and then run again over that data?

Comment: Yeah, that was how I got it down to this size. I was just hoping there might be another way--but you're right, I can always do that.